# Python str.strip() with regex filtering unexpected characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm running into an issue that I hope is simple, however I've run into a wall trying to figure it out.  I'm attempting to strip the DateTime timestamp from the beginning of each line in a file, however the returned information is cutting off some of the characters that I'd like to keep.  I was fairly sure my regex is OK, and based on the regex.group() output, it looks good.  I find that lines with the letters "c" and "e" seem to get their characters trimmed off, while other lines work as expected.

Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)

[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> line2 = '[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] ceeeeest'
>>> a = re.match(r'(\[[A-Za-z]{3}\s)?([A-Za-z]{3})(\s+)([0-9]{1,4})(\s+)([0-9]{2})(:)([0-9]{2})(:)([0-9]{2})(\s[0-9]{1,4})?(\])?', line2, re.I)
>>> a.group()
'[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010]'
>>> a.groups()
('[Wed ', 'Dec', ' ', '01', ' ', '10', ':', '24', ':', '24', ' 2010', ']')
>>> b = a.group()
>>> b
'[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010]'
>>> c = line2.strip(b)
>>> c
'st'
>>>
```

I expect C to be "ceeeeest"

OR

```
>>> line = '[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] testc'
>>> a = re.match(r'(\[[A-Za-z]{3}\s)?([A-Za-z]{3})(\s+)([0-9]{1,4})(\s+)([0-9]{2})(:)([0-9]{2})(:)([0-9]{2})(\s[0-9]{1,4})?(\])?', line, re.I)
>>> a.group()
'[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010]'
>>> a.groups()
('[Wed ', 'Dec', ' ', '01', ' ', '10', ':', '24', ':', '24', ' 2010', ']')
>>> b = a.group()
>>> c = line.strip(b)
>>> c
'test'
>>>
```

I expect c to be "testc"

Is there something very basic I am missing here?  Please enlighten me.  Thank you.

Comment: `str.strip` is not doing what you think it is doing. Please re-read the documentation.

Comment: c, e  and spaces are in b so strip removes them all from c

Comment: Are there other lines that have `[]`?

Comment: No other lines have [ ] luckily.  Ok, I will re-read strip documentation.  I see now that it is stripping any of the individual characters/digits from the beginning and end of the string that are contained in a.group() output.  Is there a best way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve by "stripping" out only the entire regex match string?

Comment: Is it appropriate to change the title of this question?  I keep finding it when I actually do want help with a regex strip not a standard replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) will remove all characters from the beginning and end of the string that are in the argument. You probably want to use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) instead.

```
>>> line = '[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] testc'
>>> line.replace('[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010]', '')
' testc'
```

You can get rid of the leading white space by using [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip), or use `str.strip` if you want to get rid of trailing white space too (the default arguments are white space).

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  Thank you Jared!  I've learned my lesson about str.strip()

Comment: Basically I have many configuration files that may or may not have dateTime or other junk in front of the text I want to collect on each line.  I need to find the junk, strip it and store the rest of the line.  This method seems easiest and most readable for now to strip it off. I'll have to incorporate a `str.lstrip()` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is `'[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010]'` so then you strip any of the characters that are in b from `c` so everything bar `ct` get removed:

```
'[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] ceeeeest'
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
 # all in [Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010]
```

So only `st` remain as they are the only two characters no in `b`, strip will keep stripping from both ends until it hits char not in the set:

```
In [3]: s = "fooboaroof"

In [4]: s.strip("foo")
Out[4]: 'boar'
```

If the date is always at the start which it must be if you are using match, when you get a match the simplest would be to split:

```
line2 = '[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] ceeeeest'

print(line2.split("] ", 1)[1])
```

Or:

```
 print(line2[len(a.group()):].lstrip())
```

Comment: No worries,  are there other similar lines to your date lines?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are using `strip` incorrectly. Instead, since you already have matching working, slice off the number of characters from the start of the string.

```
result = line[:len(a.group())]
print(result)
# prints ' testc'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have repeat items with same pattern in your string, you can use regex find all the match then replace it to empty string

```
import re
pattern = r'\[\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}\] '
for p in re.findall(pattern,line):
   line = line.replace(p,'')
```

Answer (score -1):

If I get what you're attempting to do right, you can just use a regex to extract the word/sentence afterwards:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?:\s*\[.*?\])(.*)')
sentence = regex.findall(line)[0].strip()
```

Note that I have omitted the verification that you had in your regex, you can still use it.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to `strip` (that is, discard) the date and time information, and if the information is in the format you represent, try this:

```
#! python3

lines = [
    '[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] ceeeeest',
    '[Wed Dec 01 10:24:24 2010] testc',
    'just a plain old line',
    '       indented',
    '      with [brackets]',
    '[BOGUS! This should be disallowed!',
    '[][][] Three pairs',
]

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('['):
        try:
            line = line[line.index(']')+2:]
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid formatting: open [ with no close!')
        else:
            print(line)
    else:
        print('Ho hum, nothing interesting about:', line)
```