# The issue of multiple characters operation in str.strip()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, strip

I have read the post [Python str.strip() with regex filtering unexpected characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508758/python-str-strip-with-regex-filtering-unexpected-characters) and [The official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) (this is for python 2, however, in python 3, it doesn't exist anymore).

I got a little bit confused. As a result, I made the experiment as below.

```
>>> 'hello'.strip('o')
'hell'
>>> 'hello.hello'.strip('.hello')
''
>>> 'hello.hello'.strip('.o')
'hello.hell'
>>> 'hello.hello'.strip('o.')
'hello.hell'
>>> 'Hello.hello'.strip('H')
'ello.hello'
>>> 'Hello.hello'.strip('H.')
'ello.hello'
>>> 'HEllo.hello'.strip('E')
'HEllo.hello'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('E')
'HEllo.hEllo'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('HE')
'llo.hEllo'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('El')
'HEllo.hEllo'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('Eo')
'HEllo.hEll'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('.h')
'HEllo.hEllo'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('o.h')
'HEllo.hEll'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('o-h')
'HEllo.hEll'
>>> 'HEllo.hEllo'.strip('hello')
'HEllo.hE'
>>> 'hello.hello'.strip('hello')
'.'
```

I have no idea about some of the results above.

Can anyone give me a explanation?

And why this area is removed from python 3 documentation?

Comment: [Python 3 does are here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) All it does is remove letters from the ends of the string until the string doesn't start or end with any of the letters in the set of letters passed in to `strip()`. What part are you confused about?

Comment: @MarkMeyer, Thanks, I understood. In the most case, It is better to use str.replace fucntion.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, `.strip()` considers the string argument as an set of characters. Then, it goes to both the start and end of the string, and removes characters found in the set until it finds a character not in the set. Consider this:

```
>>> '#TEST#'.strip('#') # strips the #'s at the front and end
'TEST'
>>> '#TEST#'.strip('#T') # strips T's and #'s off of the front and end 
'ES'
>>> '#TEST#'.strip('T#') # the order of the chars in the argument doesn't matter
'ES'
>>> '#TEST#'.strip('#ES') # removes the #'s, but not the E or S as the T's "obstruct" strip()
'TEST'
>>> '#TEST#'.strip('T') # will remove nothing, as the #'s "obstruct" strip()
'#TEST#'
```

Also, as noted by Mark Meyer, the docs can be found at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip.